# What "..." means in Javascript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I am learning Redux, React and ES6. I already developed with JS, but this new world of ES6 are surprising me with a lot of new things like "=>" to declare arrow functions and other. However, in this new Redux studies, I confront with `...` in middle of my code.

Bellow I have an example:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'

const userReducer = (state={}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_NAME':
            state = {...state, name: action.payload};
            break;
        case 'CHANGE_AGE':
            state = {...state, age: action.payload};
            break;
    }
    return state;
};

const tweetsReducer = (state=[], action) => {
    return state;
};

const reducers = combineReducers ({
    user: userReducer,
    tweetsReducer: tweetsReducer,
});


const store = createStore(reducers);

store.subscribe(() =>
    console.log('The chage was: ', store.getState())
);

store.dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_NAME', payload: 'Will'})
store.dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_AGE', payload: 21});
```

If I replace
`state = {...state, name: action.payload};`
 and
`state = {...state, age: action.payload};`
 with
`state.name = action.payload;`
 and
`state.age = action.payload;`
it works, but the age was inserted into object together name and in first case the name was inserted and after age was inserted.

Why does it happen? How can I use `...` in my future codes? Is it just in related with states?

Comment: `...` is the spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Thank you! I didn`t found when I asked. So, it is really duplicate. However, thanks for your answers.

Comment: @hackerrdave: [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the link! that helped to clear it up

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's called the *spread operator*.

It unpacks values from an object or array, into another object or array. For example, using arrays:

```
a1  = [1, 2, 3]
a2  = [4, 5, 6]
a12 = [...a1, ...a2] // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The same semantics apply to objects:

```
o1  = { foo: 'bar' }
o2  = { bar: 'baz' }
o12 = { ...o1, ...o2 } // { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' }
```

You can use it to shallow-copy objects and arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
aCopy = [...a] // [1, 2, 3], on a new array

o = { foo: 'bar' }
oCopy = { ...o } // { foo: 'bar' }, on a new object
```

Check out the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), an excellent source for all things javascript.

Comment: Thank you! I didn`t found when I asked. So, it is really duplicate. However, thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's actually two different things IMO because the spread operator is part of the official spec whereas the object-spread syntax is still in the early stage of the tc39 process. What it means is that this two very different behaviour, the spread operator does a lot more than "unpacking".

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508).